# How to change the font color of both label and input onfocus of an inputbox and change it back on blur

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, onfocus

I have attached a plunker link for what ive did

http://plnkr.co/edit/JlARpFiVEFryAhgxgWJm?p=preview

```css
     input[attribute=flag]:focus {
      color: red;
    }
    
    input[attribute=flag]{
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
 <form name="Form" class="form-horizontal " style="padding-left:9%;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-11  ">
                <label for="inputEmail"  class="control-label" >Email</label><br>
                 <input type="email" attribute=flag class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernameLogin" name="username"  required="">
              </div>
            </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-11 "><br>
                <label for="inputPassword"  class="control-label">Password</label><br>
                 <input type="password"  attribute=flag  class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernamePassword"  name="password" required="">
             </div>
            </div>
            
              <div class="form-group last">
                <div class="col-sm-11"><br>
                  <button type="submit" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-myprimary">LOG IN</button>
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
```

`Onfocus` of input i want to change the color of both label and input.
Right now im able to chnage the color of input but how to change label color onfocus and change it back to other color on blur.If anyone has idea please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: is this something you want done @radiance88 https://jsfiddle.net/estvwpvz/1/ check this and let me know

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos Thanks for your answer..this is what i want..but can i do it in javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: let me try and redoit but i suggest try using jquery its easy mate

Comment: @radiance88 checkout this fiddle mate https://jsfiddle.net/estvwpvz/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try with **[focusin](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/)** and **[focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)** effect.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/k0rac6o9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").on("focusin", function() {
    $(this).siblings("label").css("color","red");
    $(this).css("color","red");
});

$("input").on("focusout", function() {
    $(this).siblings("label").css("color","green");
    $(this).css("color","green");
})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

check my fiddle mate and let me know i have done this using jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/estvwpvz/5/

```
var divs  = document.getElementsByClassName('inputBorderStyle');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
  document.getElementsByClassName('inputBorderStyle')[i].addEventListener("focusin", myFunction);
  document.getElementsByClassName('inputBorderStyle')[i].addEventListener("focusout", myFunctionout);
}

function myFunction() {
    this.style.color= "red";
    this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].style.color = 'red';
}
function myFunctionout() {
    this.style.color= "white";
    this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].style.color = 'black';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type=email], input[type=password]').focus(function(){
     $(this).closest('div').find('label').css({color:'red'})
  });
  $('input[type=email], input[type=password]').blur(function(){
     $(this).closest('div').find('label').css({color:'#000'})
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

 .inputBorderStyle{
 border:0;
 box-shadow:none !important;
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 border-radius:0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 }
 input[attribute=flag]:focus {
  color: red;
}

input[attribute=flag]{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <form name="Form" class="form-horizontal " style="padding-left:9%;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-11  ">
            <label for="inputEmail"  class="control-label" >Email</label><br>
             <input type="email" attribute=flag class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernameLogin" name="username"  required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-11 "><br>
            <label for="inputPassword"  class="control-label">Password</label><br>
             <input type="password"  attribute=flag  class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernamePassword"  name="password" required="">
         </div>
        </div>
        
          <div class="form-group last">
            <div class="col-sm-11"><br>
              <button type="submit" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-myprimary">LOG IN</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
  </body>

</html>
```

The `focus` and `blur`events allow you to bind corresponding events when an HTML element receives focus and is out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onfocus and onblur event on the inputs (without jQuery)

```
var userField = document.getElementById("usernameLogin");

userField.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    this.parent.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].style.color = 'red';
});

userField.addEventListener("blur",function(){
    this.parent.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].style.color = 'green';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use jquery, to attach event focus to the input and the label after that add class to input and to the the label  and detach the class on blur

$("input").on("focus",function(){
    $(this).addClass("focusclass")
    $(this).closest(".col-md-11").first().addClass("Labelfocusclass")  
}    
$("input").on("blur",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("focusclass")
    $(this).closest(".col-md-11").first().removeClass("Labelfocusclass")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### **JavaScript Solution:**

Use `onfocus` and `onblur` events like this:

```js
function changeColor(obj) {
    document.getElementById(obj).style.color = "red";
}

function removeColor(obj) {
    document.getElementById(obj).style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.inputBorderStyle {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
input[attribute=flag]:focus {
    color: red;
}
input[attribute=flag] {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<form name="Form" class="form-horizontal " style="padding-left:9%;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-11  "><br>
      <label for="inputEmail"  class="control-label" id="email">Email</label><br>
      <input type="email" attribute=flag class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernameLogin" name="username"  required="" onfocus="changeColor('email')" onblur="removeColor('email')">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-11 "><br>
      <label for="inputPassword"  class="control-label" id="password">Password</label><br>
      <input type="password"  attribute=flag  class="form-control inputBorderStyle box"  id="usernamePassword"  name="password" required="" onfocus="changeColor('password')" onblur="removeColor('password')">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group last">
    <div class="col-sm-11"><br>
      <button type="submit" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-myprimary">LOG IN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Good luck. Have a great day!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that has solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem but since my reputation is less than 15 i cant accept answer.sorry! But this is the solution.Thanks again.